# Have I properly sorted these runtimes in order of growth?

Tags: math, big-o, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

I am doing this small task which I have to arrange asymptotic runtime in ascending order. Here are the runtimes:

[image]

Here is the order I believe they should go in:

```
log10(n^4), n^3, 2^((log4n)), 2^(100n), e^pi^4096, n! + 12^1000
```

Is this correct? Or are there any errors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that the ordering you've given here is correct. Here are a few things to think about:

1. Notice that 2<sup>log<sub>4</sub> n</sup> = 2<sup>(log<sub>2</sub> n / log<sub>2</sub> 4)</sup> = 2<sup>(log<sub>2</sub> n) / 2</sup>. Can you simplify this expression?
2. How fast does the function e<sup>π<sup>4096</sup></sup> grow as a function of n?

Hope this helps!

Comment: So only 2log4 n and e^π^4096 are in incorrect order then?

Comment: @Walle Both of them are in the wrong place. Can you figure out where they should go?

Comment: I specifically compared them by pairs and figured there's no way 2log4 n would go before n^3. Can you drop some hints

Comment: Did you try simplifying 2^((log_2 n) / 2)? If so, what did you get? If you're stuck, let me know and I can give you a hint.

Comment: Does it equal n/2 ? As for e^π^4096 since it doesn't involve n then the run time would remain as constant as function n grows, right?

Comment: You're right about e^pi^4096. As for the other one, it's not n/2, but that's close. As a hint, a^(b/c) = (a^b)^(1/c).

Comment: I get it now. But does constant have to be the most dominating runtime or the least? I was thinking of the biggest

Comment: Think about really, really, really huge values of n. Which will be smallest?